# authenticated and anonymous for the same endpoind (spring security)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What i want is, for

```
localhost:8080/home -> should be open to only authenticated - home page after login
localhost:8080/home?msg=asdsada -> should be open to anonymous - for login errors like wrong password
```

This is endpoind:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/home"})
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(
                                     @RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false) String message) throws IOException
```

I tried to add this to security config of spring

```
.regexMatchers("/home").authenticated()
.regexMatchers("/home?msg=.*").permitAll()
```

So config became like this:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(anonymousEndpoints).anonymous()
            .antMatchers(permittedEndpoints).permitAll()
            .regexMatchers("/home").authenticated()
            .regexMatchers("/home?msg=.*").anonymous()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
```

But for wrong password, it does not go to endpoind

```
localhost:8080/home?msg=asdsada
```

For logged user, it can go to

```
localhost:8080/home
```

also it can go to

```
localhost:8080/home?msg=asdsada
```

What am I doing wrong? I can also use endpoind to check if logged in or not. Like:

But i want spring scurity to do this. Give 403 forbidden for example.

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/home"})
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(
                                     @RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false) String message) throws IOException{


        Authentication authentication = SecurityUtil.getAuthentication(false);
        if (authentication != null) {
            logger.info("User: {} already logged in, redirecting to dashboard", authentication.getName());
            web.response.sendRedirect("/dashboard");
            return null;
        }
else{//not logged in

if (msg != null)//and msg is not null so like wrong password
//do smth
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't configure the specific path in Spring Security Config, just analyze it in the controller method. In config set permitAll for this path, but add an authentication or principal parameter in the method signature:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/home"})
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false) String message, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    if (msg != null) {
        ...
    } else if (!authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

P.S. Method arguments: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments